# How to implement limited file access in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, lamp, file-permissions

I'm working on an application (LAMP) where users can upload files to the server but cannot share it's files with other users. So, my problem is to implement a secure mechanism that ensures user A cannot access to files uploaded by user B.

My approach is this:

1. Each user has a folder for its files (/upload/userA)
2. Add a .htaccess file to redirect all access to /upload folder to a PHP script
3. Check if the user has permission to access to the subdirectory (/userA)

Can you see any drawback in this approach? Any better alternative?

Comment: One drawback I can think of is that `.htaccess` files are rather slow, and taxing on servers - it'd be much better off being set in the server config file.

Comment: Instead of making hard references to files, you can make something like `download.php?id=1234` and just check for `1234` from database whether user has privileges to download the file and do not show the physical path to user at all.

Comment: I would second @Ahmet and add that a good practice for saving files in a "secured" way is storing them outside of your domain (yet still on your server).  Then use download.php?id-1234 to call the file.

Comment: I'm moving to an answer.

Comment: Interesting.. can you explain why is more secure to store in other server? Thx

Comment: It does not have to be on another server but outside of the area accessible via HTTP so visitors will never have a direct link to the file but a script that routes the traffic.  So you can have /mydomain.com/htdocs/ for web/php and /mydomain.com/secured/ for files.  The latter folder is not accessible via HTTP (hope this makes sense...)

Comment: Ok, this makes a lot of sense! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making hard references to files, you can make something like `download.php?id=1234` and just check for `1234` from database whether user has privileges to download the file and do not show the physical path to user at all.

With HTTP headers, you can force users to download file with a filename you have desired (stored on database). Allowing users to directly access their files from physical paths is not a good idea and if you try to make a hook with `.htaccess` upon each request, that will be more expensive, indeed.

Most systems consider generating some random strings or GUIDs that you can't simply access someone else's file by changing a character randomly. i.e. in Facebook images, `../187170_697610597_4628627_q.jpg` there is that complicated URL which users can directly access but can not guess another image URL by changing a few digits, that's too difficult but not safe and does not meet your requirements.